# Cloud Functions for Firebase infinite running then quota exceeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I got stuck when edit example function generateThumbnail, which is convert to multiple image resolution but unfortunately, it raised some exceptions then it running continuously util system report quota exceeded. Would you show me how to stop running process in Functions?

Comment: did you find a reason behind this? Why after deleting functions still you are getting the error?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to stop a function like that is to deploy an empty function for it instead, or to deploy an index.js without the function present.

Comment: I did as you said but I still got error quota exceeded milisecond after milisecond

Comment: Interesting answer. Deserves to be highlighted in the documentation, or in Firebase questions, as this is a recurring fear of each developper attempting to go cloud.